# Layer initialisation in while_loop: "Variable initializer inside control-flow construct"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm running into an issue whereby if a layer with trainable parameters is used for the first time inside a tensorflow while_loop, I get the error:

> ValueError: Initializer for variable lambda_1/while/dense_1/kernel/ is from inside a control-flow construct, such as a loop or conditional. When creating a variable inside a loop or conditional, use a lambda as the initializer.

From searching around, the standard approach for handling this is to introduce a lambda where any variables are being defined - however this is not the case for a layer execution.

```
from keras.layers import *
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Model

dense_layer = Dense(1, input_shape=(1,))

def step(val):
    avg_val = tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_sum(val,axis=1),axis=1)
    new_val = dense_layer(avg_val)
    return concatenate([new_val, avg_val])

def cond(val):
    return tf.less(K.shape(val)[1], 10)

def the_loop(src):
    return tf.while_loop(cond, step, [src],
                       shape_invariants=[tf.TensorShape([None, None])])



src = Input(shape=[None])
out = Lambda(the_loop)(src)
model = Model(src, out)
```

That's a (fairly stupid) MWE but it illustrates the issue - any suggestions? I previously got around this (in my more complex model) as I needed the value used to initialize the loop (src in this case) was calculated using those layers, but I'm attempting a different method of initialising the loop which doesn't allow for this.